Our site description should be changed to match our new welcome message
We asked for and we received a new welcome message for our site:

This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for practitioners, researchers, and students in cognitive science, psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry.


I believe our description should also be changed everywhere else (the /about page, stackexchange.com, etc.)
What does everyone else think?

It's on the about page http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/about

@BenBrocka well so it is! This contradicts with what Shog9 said... Clarification being requested.

Ok, I went ahead and did this (and then didn't get back here to respond, sorry Josh). 
Not updated on SE.com yet. I probably forgot something there.

Thanks so much for this

YES
The new description is our elevator pitch and should be consistent everywhere. Everywhere should have our new description. But let us not forget about the name change.

I haven't forgotten about the name change :-) Just trying to stick to one topic at a time so we can have actionable items to take to the team.
